# Where this blue circle with white plus inside comes from?

Tags: objective-c

Does anyone knows where this blue circle with white plus comes from? It is in many apple apps. Can't find in Interface Builder.
Thanks.

Comment: What you are talking about?where is blue circle?where is white plus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to get add symbol

```
UIButton *myButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about a `UIButton` with the `UIButtonTypeContactAdd` style.